# Python bs4 follow links in a list returned from a css selector

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have used BS4 and a css selector to identify the part of the tree I want and that works. However, now I have a list of elements, containing links, and I want to extract the link and follow it for each one.

The issue is now that bs4 has returned a list I cannot use find('a') or similar to extract each one.

Is there a better way to do this?

My code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# from lxml import etree

response = requests.get("https://www.racingaustralia.horse/home.aspx")
if response.status_code != 200:
    print("Error fetching page")
    exit()
else:
    content = response.content
print("Sucessful")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.select("body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(9) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(5) > ul:nth-child(2)")
for item in results:
    print(item)
```

And my output

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=NSW">New South Wales</a></li>
<li><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=VIC">Victoria</a></li>
<li><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=QLD">Queensland</a></li>
<li><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=WA">Western Australia</a></li>
<li><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=SA">South Australia</a></li>
<li><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=TAS">Tasmania</a></li>
<li><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=ACT">Australian Capital Territory</a></li>
<li><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=NT">Northern Territory</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `results` is returning an empty list: `[]`

Comment: @MendelG if I test the lists length
print(len(results)) # = 1

Comment: Intresting. I get `0` for `len(results)` See if my answer below worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running your code, the output of `results` was `[]`, so I changed the CSS selector to:

```
results = soup.select("#home-menu > ul > li:nth-child(5) > ul li a")

for item in results:
    print(item["href"])
```

Output:

```
/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=NSW
/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=VIC
/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=QLD
/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=WA
/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=SA
/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=TAS
/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=ACT
/FreeFields/Calendar_Results.aspx?State=NT
```

---

However, if you do indeed get an output for `results` with *your* above code, try narrowing down your CSS selector to also include the `li` and `a`:

```
results = soup.select("body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(9) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(5) > ul:nth-child(2) li a")

for item in results:
    print(item["href"])
```

Comment: Thanks, will review. Yes I indeed get a result from the code a list of length 1.

Comment: This works better because I now get a return of list length 8.

Comment: @sayth the problem was with your Selector. How did you find the CSS selector? I'm assuming you just copied the path with your browser?

Comment: Yes using a tool called SelectorsHub and copied the Rel CSS path

Comment: It will be potentially faster to apply > where ever it is applicable rather than filtering on all children `body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(9) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(5) > ul:nth-child(2) > li >a`

Answer (score 1):

I would have gone with a more robust [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector, specifying contains (*) operator, to filter on `href` containing `Calendar_Results` substring

```
print([i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href*=Calendar_Results]')])
```